# Rails paperclip static files with absolute url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a model with one paperclip attachment :image

**Model:**

```
class HomeScreen < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create { !HomeScreen.has_record? }
  validates :image, :attachment_presence => true
  attr_accessible :image
  has_attached_file :image

  def self.has_record?
    if HomeScreen.last
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

show method of my conttroller should return image with relative path but json should return absolute url with domain, how can I do that?

**Controller:**

```
class HomeScreenController < ApplicationController
  # GET /home_screen
  def show    
    @home_screen = HomeScreen.last

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @home_screen }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

According to a [github issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/584), you can do the following:

```
image_uri = URI.join(request.url, @home_screen.image.url)
```

This will be an `URI` object, which can be converted to a `String` with its `.to_s`

Answer (score 1):

According to the same [github issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/584#issuecomment-1985865), it is cleaner to use `ActionController::Base.asset_host` so it would result the helper:

```
  def add_host_prefix(url)
    URI.join(ActionController::Base.asset_host, url)
  end
```

This supposes you have in every `/config/environments/<environment>.rb` file the following:

```
Appname::Application.configure do

  # ....

  config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000' # Locally

  # ....

end
```